# Write pandas dataframe to csv file line by line

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a pandas dataframe to a CSV file with the associated headers in tact row by row. I've accomplished this using

```
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(old_df).T
```

Which appears to produce a format (I think a dict?) where I can then write to a csv file line by line using the following

```
    with open('new.csv', 'a') as f:
        new_df.to_csv(f)
```

However in the CSV file I have two new columns both with incremental numbers (1,2,3..) for each row. The second column has the key 'Unnamed: 0' while the first column has no key (i.e. key = '').

I would prefer to not have these headers, I can delete the second on using

```
del new_df['Unnamed: 0']
```

but I can't do this for the second as it has no key (del new_df[''] does not work).

Would anyone know either how to delete the first column or a better way to write a dataframe to a csv file row by row..

Comment: Just slice and write: `df.iloc[:, 1:].to_csv(...)`

Comment: To be sure, please provide some actual data. What is it you're getting. How do you want it written. Words don't help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need parameter `index=False` for not write first column called index (`0,1,2...`) and `header=False` for no columns names:

```
df.to_csv('file', index=False, header=False)
```